# How to create Class Mediator in wso2 esb /

Tags: wso2, esb

I would like to create class mediator. I tried with ordinary java class i put into components/lib folder then i restart this system.

Can anyone tell me step by step procedure.

Answer (score 4):

1. Write a class which implements org.apache.synapse.Mediator and override the mediate(MessageContext mc) method and create a jar file.

   ```
   public class SimpleClassMediator implements Mediator {
     private String varible1="10";
     private String varible2="10";

   public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {

   //To test you can print something here
   return true;

   }

    //getters and setters

   }
   ```
2. Copy the jar to ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib and start the ESB.
3. Then in synapse config you can call this mediator as [follow](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Class+Mediator).

   ```
   class name="packageName.ClassName"
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much, the above link so much useful

Comment: @ Isuru do you have any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035829/how-to-call-class-mediator-property-value-inside-the-another-mediator-class

Answer (score 3):

1. You can create class mediator easily by extending the "AbstractMediator".
2. Mediator can be an OSGI build or jar file. Both  can be deployed with WSO2 ESB.  If You need to deploy the Jar file in to /repository/components/lib directory. If it is an OSGI bundle, it must be deployed in to  /repository/components/dropins directory.  If there are any external dependent libraries, you can put them it to  /repository/components/lib directory
3. Update the synapse configure with the full qualified class name

You can find sample  more detail from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/11/28/how-to-wso2esb-how-to-write-custom-mediator/). It contains a sample mediator code that you can look in to.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. First create a Maven module e.g org.wso2.carbon.mediator and then  create e.g ESBMessageMediator class  which is extended from AbstractMediator. 

2. Above maven module can be configured as OSGI budle or jar file.

3. Build the module using maven.

4. If it is OSGI bundle put it in to the /repository/components/dropins else put it to the 
   /repository/components/lib

5. configure synapse.xml file located in the "/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default"
  e.g <class name="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.ESBMessageMediator">
    <property name="defaultPercentage" value="10"/>
</class>
6.Run the ESB and try to create a proxy service by adding the above meaditor as class mediator.if it load succesfully it is done.
```

Answer (score -1):

you can read about class mediator in WSO2 in this site [[1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Class+Mediator)]

You can write the logic in the mediate() method :)